# Maximum Single Ply Branching Factor for Legal Checkers Boards

Tags: branching-factors, checkers

I am writing a checkers move generation function in C that will be extended to Python. It is much easier to handle the possible boards in a fixed size array to pass back to Python.

Basically, I build out possible boards and add them to this array:

```
uint32_t boards[x][3];
```

Therefore, the optimal value for x should be the maximum single ply branching factor out of all possible legal board states.

I am not sure if I am being very clear, so here is an example:

For tic-tac-toe this value would be 9, as the first move has the greatest number of possible directly resulting board states, out of all of the legal boards.

Has this value been calculated for checkers? Has a program like Chinook derived a reasonably close number?

Thank you for your help!